# How to add email address from email to existing contact

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, email, evolution, contacts

Ubuntu 12.04

I have a couple of email accounts but store my contacts on Google to sync with my phone. I am trying to setup an email client so it seamlessly integrates with my various email accounts (yahoo and gmail based) and take my contacts from Google with bidirectional sync.

I have tried Thunderbird with a Google add on and Evolution. Both appear to work but the contacts integration is suboptimal. If I have an email from someone in my contacts list, I can only add them as a new contact rather than selecting the existing contact and updating it with the extra details. Evolution did seem to support this if I happened to type in the exact name of the contact (you can't browse your contacts) but it crashes when it tries to do it.

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work seemlessly?

Thanks

Lee.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Email address in the mail header (e.g. in the preview pane), select "Copy EMail address". Then open contacts, double-click the contact you want to add the address to, and paste it. Not the easiest or most intuitive way, but the only one I know to work (just verified: still does on 12.04 ;).